# How to convert function output to Unit with Kotlin

Tags: function, return, kotlin

I have troubles with a function in Kotlin that should return Unit, but due to a usage of another function returning a Boolean, there is a type mismatch.

Here is a contrived example:

```
fun printAndReturnTrue(bar: Int): Boolean {
    println(bar)
    return true
}

fun foo(bar: Int): Unit = when(bar) {
    0 -> println("0")
    else -> printAndReturnTrue(bar)
}
```

Here, I actually do not care about the fact that `printAndReturnTrue` returns a boolean. I just want foo to perform side-effect operations. But the compiler warns about a type mismatch: my `else` should return a `Unit` value.

Is there a nice way to convert a value to `Unit`?

The simplest solutions I see are:

```
fun foo(bar: Int): Unit = when(bar) {
    0 -> println("0")
    else -> { 
        printAndReturnTrue(bar)
        Unit
    }
}
```

or:

```
fun foo(bar: Int): Unit = when(bar) {
    0 -> println("0")
    else -> eraseReturnValue(printAndReturnTrue(bar))
}

fun eraseReturnValue(value: Any) = Unit
```

Or I use the full function form:

```
fun foo(bar: Int): Unit { 
    when(bar) {
        0 -> println("0")
        else -> printAndReturnTrue(bar)
    }
}
```

I am sure there are some idiomatic ways to do that (or is is the last example?), but for now I did not find them.

Answer (score 14):

Unfortunaly, there's no *idiomatic* way to do this. A similiar problem, passing a lambda of type `(T) -> Boolean` to a function accepting `(T) -> Unit` lambdas has come up before, and the auto conversion required there is supposed to come to the language at some future point.

For now, you could use an extension function at the end of the `when` expression to coerce it back into a `Unit` value:

```
fun Any?.toUnit() = Unit

fun foo(bar: Int): Unit = when(bar) {
    0 -> println("0")
    else -> printAndReturnTrue(bar)
}.toUnit()
```

Alternatively, an extension property, if you happen to like that better:

```
val Any?.unit get() = Unit

fun foo(bar: Int): Unit = when(bar) {
    0 -> println("0")
    else -> printAndReturnTrue(bar)
}.unit
```

Of course you can omit the explicit `Unit` return type of the function if you use either of these.

Comment: Very good other example with the lambda type. In an afterthought I thought using the "=" version of function was not the good way, but it seems there are other valid cases where it can be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think the last is most idiomatic. Though you don't need explicit `: Unit`, it's the default for block form if no return type is specified and if you try to return something else you'll get an error.

But note a subtle detail: when `when` is used as an expression, `else` is required unless the compiler can prove all cases are handled; in the block form it's "used as a statement" and unhandled cases are ignored.

Answer (score 3):

As another alternative, you could make a higher order function that swallows the output of the function returning a value:

```
fun consume (fn: () -> Any): Unit {
  fn()
}
```

Giving:

```
fun foo(bar: Int): Unit = when(bar) {
    0 -> println("0")
    else -> consume { printAndReturnTrue(bar) }
}
```

Comment: For better readability the method can be named `toUnit`. It can even accept the value, not lambda: `fun toUnit(value: Any?): Unit {}` and the usage: `else -> toUnit(printAndReturnTrue(bar))`

Answer (score 1):

I just use a semicolon if I write in a line.

```
someExpression; Unit
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just call `.let {}` on a non-unit value to discard it (while keeping the side-effect):

```kotlin
// ...
else -> printAndReturnTrue(bar).let {}
// ...
```

`{}` is a Unit-returning function that ignores its arguments. `let` is an extension function that passes its receiver to the given lambda -- in this case, the lambda ignores it, and produces Unit, as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change return type of function to optional, it's more clear, like below:

```
fun printAndReturnTrue(bar: Int): Boolean {
    println(bar)
    return true
}

fun foo(bar: Int): Unit? = when(bar) {
    0 -> println("0")
    else -> printAndReturnTrue(bar) as? Unit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like

```
fun foo(bar: Int): Unit = when(bar) {
    0 -> println("0")
    else -> printAndReturnTrue(bar).let{ Unit }
}
```