# Discard return value to return Unit?

Tags: kotlin

I am just starting with kotlin, so, forgive me if this is a basic question, I did do some googling, but that didn't turn up anything useful.

The question is how do I convert a value to `Unit`. 
For example, in scala, if I write something like this:

```
def foo: Int = ???
def bar(x: String): Unit = x match {
  case "error" => println("There was an error")
  case _ => foo
```

}

The return type of the `match` expression is `Any`, but it is discarded by the compiler and `Unit` is returned by the function.

But doing something like this in kotlin:

```
fun bar(x: String): Unit = when(x) {
 "error" ->  println("There was an error") 
 else -> foo()
}
```

it complains about the `foo` part: `inferred type is Int but Unit was expected`

I know, that in this case, I can just get rid of the `=`, and put the body inside a block instead, that works, but I am looking for a general solution. What I was able to come with so far is just `foo.let {}`, but it seems kinda clumsy, especially if there are many cases like this where it needs to be done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert function output to Unit with Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47370414/how-to-convert-function-output-to-unit-with-kotlin)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can [create an extension method on Any object and call it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47371111/172690). I just prefer to use the name `discard()` rather than `toUnit()`, since I feel it conveys better the intent:

```
fun Any?.discard() = Unit

fun foo(): Int = 3

fun bar(x: String): Unit = when (x) {
    "error" -> println("There was an error")
    else -> foo().discard()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do that out of the box, but you can make an extension function for this:

```
fun Any?.unit() = Unit
```

Then use it as:

```
fun bar(x: String): Unit = when(x) {
    "error" ->  println("There was an error") 
    else -> foo().unit()
}
```

Alternatively, make `when` a statement and not an expression:

```
fun bar(x: String) {
    when(x) {
        "error" ->  println("There was an error") 
        else -> foo()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three solutions to your problem, which come to my mind:

1. Make `when` a statement instead of expression, so its result does not get returned:

   ```
   fun bar(x: String) {
        when(x) {
           "error" ->  println("There was an error") 
           else -> foo()
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use an **extension** to convert values to `Unit`:

   ```
   fun Any?.asUnit() = Unit
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   fun bar(x: String): Unit =
      when (x) {
          "error" -> println("There was an error")
           else -> foo().asUnit()
   }
   ```
3. Wrap the call into higher-order function call that returns `Unit`, e.g. `with`:

   ```
   fun bar(x: String): Unit = with(x){
       when (x) {
           "error" -> println("There was an error")
           else -> foo()
       }
   }
   ```