# Kotlin function: Required Unit? Found Int

Tags: android, kotlin, higher-order-functions

Repeatedly facing this issue in Kotlin

```
fun test(){
        compute { foo -> Log.e("kotlin issue", "solved") } // This line is //showing error
    }

    fun compute(body: (foo:String) -> Unit?){
        body.invoke("problem solved")
    }
```

I am getting the error in Studio. Here is a screenshot. [image]

Comment: Why is it using `Unit?`? I don't think there is ever a reason to use this type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The lambda you pass to the `compute` function has to return `Unit?`. Right now, you're returning the result of the `Log.e()` call, which returns an `Int` representing the number of bytes written to the output. If all you want to do is log a message in the lambda, you can explicitly return `Unit` at the end of the it like so:

```
fun test() {
    compute { foo -> 
        Log.e("kotlin issue", "solved") 
        Unit
    }
}
```

Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47370414/4465208) where other means of converting a return value to `Unit` are discussed.

Comment: Thanks. It worked, I will accept it as soon as it will be available. But can you shed some light, or any link about how just writing Unit would work? You are neither initializing any object, or typecasting it.

Comment: `Unit` is actually a singleton `object`, see the source [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/builtins/src/kotlin/Unit.kt)  :)

Answer (score 3):

Android [`Log.e`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) returns `Int` where as the `body` parameter specifies that the return type should be `Unit?`.

You need to either change `compute` method signature like so:

```
fun compute(body: (foo: String) -> Unit) { body.invoke("problem solved") }
```

Or change the invocation like so:

```
compute { foo -> Log.e("kotlin issue", "solved"); null }
```

Or wrap the compute to change the invocation:

```
fun myCompute(body: (foo: String) -> Any?) { compute { body(it); null } }
```

and then invoke it as you expect:

```
myCompute { foo -> Log.e("kotlin issue", "solved") }
```